# How brush convert to color (UWP)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have convert "Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush" to "Windows.UI.Color". But VS return error. Tell me please how can I do this conversion correctly?

Comment: Add some code to your question and the error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot convert a brush to a color. The concept of a brush cannot be reduced to a color, as it could be a gradient of colors, or an image etc.

The conversion only makes sense for the special case of [SolidColorBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush). I am guessing that's what you are after. Here is how you do it in code:

```
Windows.UI.Color colorFromBrush;
if (brush is SolidColorBrush)
    colorFromBrush = (brush as SolidColorBrush).Color;
else
    throw new Exception("Can't get color from a brush that is not a SolidColorBrush");
```

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Awesome Explanation

Answer (score 1):

You **can** convert Brush to color, but you have to write it explicitly.
To do so just do this:

```
StackPanel pane = new StackPanel()
{
Background = Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Windows.UI.Color() { A = 255, R = 25, B = 0, G = 0})
}
```

This works for **EVERY** single *UIElement* as long as you assign the ***Background*** property properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround if you're converting it to a string, then the string to bytes and then the bytes to color:

```
var brushString = Foreground.ToString(); // brushString equals "#FF000000" (in case of black brush)
var brushWithoutHash = brushString.Substring(1); // brushWithoutHash equals "FF000000"
var color = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToByte(brushWithoutHash.Substring(0, 2), 16), Convert.ToByte(brushWithoutHash.Substring(2, 2), 16), Convert.ToByte(brushWithoutHash.Substring(4, 2), 16), Convert.ToByte(brushWithoutHash.Substring(6, 2), 16));
```

in the last line you take the hexadecimal string values and convert them to a byte.

Make sure that you're brush is made out of one single color and not null, otherwise you'll get an exception.